# SlidingDrawer Android:: looking for a 3 state solution

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-sliding

I am looking to make a `slidingDrawer`handle three states: Default being 50% open, and then a 100% open and a fully closed state.   I was wondering if anyone has created their own version of the `sliding drawer` or has an elegant solution for doing this with the existing `Android Sliding Drawer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a free source on GitHub. Here is the link [SlidingUpPanel GitHub](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

you can implement it in your code and set the values you need for your three states.

Comment: I appreciate that.. and it is definitely something i may use in the future, but the problem with using it here is my view is a DrawerLayout, because i have two side menus.  The class above needs to be the root layout which i can not do for this.